# htaccess RewriteRule directory contents to a different domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I'm wanting to do is redirect requests from; :

```
https://olddomain.com/assets/pathtofile.png
```

to

```
https://newdomain.com/domain-assets/pathtofile.png
```

Here's what I have so far;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule assets https://newdomain.com/domain-assets [L,R]
```

Comment: Try this   RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
        RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 RewriteRule ^assets(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/domain-assets$1 [L,R]
```